# In Drupal 7, errors for file_managed field remain even when fixed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-files

I've been beating my head over this one and can't figure out how to solve it.

I have a content type with an image field, and I've set minimum dimension requirements for the field.  The form to create or edit nodes of this type includes a field of type "managed_file" to deal with the upload of images.  When an image is upload and it does not meet the minimum dimension requirements, a nice error message is added via ajax that reads "The specified file xxx could not be uploaded. The image is too small; the minimum dimensions are 150x150 pixels."  This is great.

When I then upload a file that does fit all requirements, however, the error message remains.

Is this a bug in Core?  Is there a good way to remove error messages in this situation when they are no longer relevant?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue [(File validation error message not removed after subsequent upload of valid file - 1792032)](http://drupal.org/node/1792032). A patch exists for Drupal 8 and that same patch should apply cleanly to Drupal 7. The issue is waiting on somebody to write tests before it can be RTBCd.

UPDATE:
This patch has been [committed to Drupal 8](https://drupal.org/node/1792032#comment-7465392). Waiting on a [backport to Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/1792032#comment-7474742).

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't supposed to appear when the file fits.

Try to push your limits a bit further or upload another file that is below your restrictions by some margin.

And kindly tell me how things went.

Muhammad.

Comment: The case I'm interested in is when the file does NOT meet the requirements, but then another one is uploaded which does.It's not a matter of my changing restrictions or the size of a file being uploaded.  The restrictions apply to users of the site and are there for a reason.